# GCC link error, relocation truncated to fit: GPREL16 against symbol error

Tags: tensorflow, gcc, bazel

I'm **cross compiling** **tensorflow r1.9** at present. The host system is ubuntu 18.04, the target system is **sw26010** (a Chinese CPU which instruction set is based on alpha). The cross compiler is based on GCC 5.3.

Due to some OS restriction, I must **static link** all libraries to tensorflow. libstdc++.a and libpthread.a. are included.

I can compile all object files successfully after some configeration. (add "//conditions:default": []," to nsync BUILD file, and add the sw2 CPU macro to double conversion BUILD file). However, I cannot link all library files and object files successfully.

Here is the error message.

/home/qh5/swgcc530/gcc-5.3.0/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/ios_init.cc:140:(.text._ZNSt8ios_base4InitD2Ev+0xf4): relocation truncated to fit: GPREL16 against symbol `std::wcerr' defined in .bss._ZSt5wcerr section in /usr/sw-mpp/swcc/swgcc530-tools/usr/sw_64sw2-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.a(globals_io.o)

Here is the CROSSTOOL for tensorflow bazel.
[CROSSTOOL on hastebin](https://hastebin.com/lokixahova.http)
I tried to use **compiler_flag: "-msmall-data"** and **compiler_flag: "-fpic"** to fix the bug, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, this error is solved by contacting the compiler team. If you have the same problem. Please seek help from the Chinese compiler team and update your compiler.